# How to identify whether to use anjency matrix or abjency array according to situation

Tags: java, c

I want to find the best method to make a graph according to the situation.If its abjacency Matrix or array

Comment: Do you use Java or C? Please just use the correct tags.

Comment: Can you show what you have done?Can you explain the problem and provide more details, which will help setup the context. A one liner is an open invitation for down votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graph on array(adjacency matrix) O(n^2) memory versus O(n*m) adjacency list(m <= n). Iterate on vertex's edges O(n), what also greater than adjacency list. Many libraries, containing graph algoritihms founded on adjacency list. But if you have tightly graph, where n ~= m, array its ok.